# mount remote devices locally (Linux)

Tags: linux

I was wondering if you can 'share' devices in Linux by overlaying the devices nodes?  For instance, is it possible to use SSH (FS) + bind to selectively bind devices locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Device nodes only provide a pointer to internal kernel structures, so they cannot be shared in this manner.